# Nested lists and percentages

Tags: html, css, css-position

It's an agreed-upon notion that it's good to keep your design and functionality separate. Fine. Let's take the separation between HTML and CSS in this case, and in particular the organisation of a menu hierarchy.

The problem with nested `<ol>`, `<ul>` and `<li>` is that they seem to be completely counterintuitive to style based on percentage (in a responsively designed setting).

**My Problem**:

I have a list that is a few layers deep, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a>Submenu 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a>Submenu 1 (1)<a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Submenu 1 (2)<a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Submenu 1 (3)<a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let's say I wanted to style this list in a way that was `relative` or `absolute` to the body of the document, for purposes of responsive web design. So I style the top `ul` with a means to continue down the list:

```
body > ul{

  position:relative;

  width:20%;

}
```

All very well. But what if I then need to subsequently give absolute positions or relative widths/heights to `<li>`'s nested deeper in the list? They now adhere to the percentage styles of the top-level `<ul>` (because it has been defined as `relative`). This basically means they need to be individually styled and calculated if I want all of the list items to be the same size compared to the `window`. The subsequent lists cannot be given the same percentage styling as the top, they need to be doubled/halved/bastardized.

This seems completely counter-intuitive to the whole process of separating style and form. The form (HTML) should determine the relationship of the data, while the style (CSS) should determine the visualisation and offer the ability to 'disjoint' the form in any way that it sees fit.

**My Questions**:

1. Is it possible to ignore a parent coordinate space that has been defined as `fixed`/`relative`/`absolute` such that `100%` means `100%` of the `body`?
2. Am I missing something in the philosophy behind the HTML/CSS relationship, and how best to utilise it?
3. If I continue with web-development, will I have torn all my hair out by the age of 35?

**Disclaimer**:

I'm looking for an answer that can bring me inner-peace, not a single fix for a single browser. If the answer is "it can't be done", then explain why and how happy you are about the fact that it can't be done.

Comment: To number 3 I can tell you that you better get used to the thought of being bald.

Comment: @SvenBieder Ha! I think I might have to start a local web development support group. We can all just sit in a circle in the basement of a community centre and weep. Classic, someone has already downvoted.

Comment: Perhaps it is a stupid idea, but have you tried to use `rem` as unit instead of `%`?

Comment: I don't get what you're after here.  If you have a `ul` that is relatively positioned to 20% of the window, and you want it's children to have that same width, you just give them 100% width. What am I missing? http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/pen/GjgFm

Comment: @SvenBieder I think it might be an interesting adventure, but backwards compatibility issues on such a fundamental aspect of my core design may rear their ugly head.

Comment: But, no, you can't ignore a parent element unless you give the child position:absolute (which negates what you may be trying to do anyway) AND the parent is not positioned.

Comment: When you need backwards compatibility then the only thing I can think of is using javascript. Then you can at every time calculate the % based on the body.

Comment: @SvenBieder Yeah I figured, but for the record I was looking for a non-javascript answer/fix/hack.

Comment: @shennan That is why I only give a comment on that possibility. When backwards compatibility is a must then it is sometimes also a must to choose a solution that is not on top of your wishlist.

Comment: @SvenBieder True. It was worth mentioning. Sorry if I seemed ungrateful...

Comment: @ChrisRockwell I take your point. But what if I wanted the nested elements (all relatively or absolutely positioned) to also be a percentage width of the window? For example, the top `<ul>` is 30% of the window, but my children need to be 80% of the window. That scenario requires logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested by what you are trying to achieve. It's not something I've ever had to do, but you have brought up an interesting point. I also think you may have mis-understood the way some of the inheritance works. Just because you put relative positioning on an element doesn't change the way the sub elements get their widths. Percentage widths always get their widths based on their parent element, whether it's relative positioned or whatever. In most cases the parent fills the space of it's parent, etc. There is definitely a certain amount of 'zen' that needs to be grasped when it comes to CSS and yes continuing in web-development could cause the loss of hair! Buy a stress ball and you should be ok :) As for heights that's a different story as it's buggy as hell and generally doesn't pick up it's parent's height.

You do have to be careful when using percentages though, if you are being to generic with your styles and you have parent/child relationships going on then indeed font-sizes can diminish as you point out. The trick is to place the percentages at the ends of the node tree in terms of styling, and place other stuff that doesn't affect itself (colours etc) on the more generic styles higher up.

In most cases you can achieve what is required, but it does take a bit of planning at times.

But as you say if you position something relative and then position something absolute at a nested level inside it will always work out it's position from the first element in it's ancestors that has been given relative or absolute positioning. I'm pretty sure there's no way around that unless you hit the javascript and do some calculations on the fly.

Comment: Is there an answer here?  It just looks like a really long comment to me.

Comment: I guess to be more concise the exact answers are:-

1. No
2. It seems that way to me
3. More than likely, web development is the most frustrating vocation I've ever been involved with, especially if dealing with legacy systems that use out of date technology.